# Inno Setupで作成したsetup.exeの発行元の設定について

Tags: windows, inno-setup

Unityで作成したWindows用アプリのsetupインストーラをInno Setupを使用して作成したのですが、提供元が不明と出てしまいます。

```
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
```

のように発行者の部分に設定はしていますが反映されません。

こちらの解決方法をご存じないでしょうか？

Inno Setupは6.0.2を使用しています。

2019/5/17追記
インストールしたアプリは正常動作することは確認しています。
`.iss` のコードは以下の通りです。

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "My App Windows"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "MY CORPORATION"
#define MyAppURL "http://www.xxxxxxxx.co.jp/"
#define MyAppExeName "My App.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppCopyright={#MyAppPublisher}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputBaseFilename=My App Windows Setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "japanese"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Japanese.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\work\Unity\workspace\app-title\My App Windows\My App.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\work\Unity\workspace\app-title\My App Windows\UnityCrashHandler32.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\work\Unity\workspace\app-title\My App Windows\UnityPlayer.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\work\Unity\workspace\app-title\My App Windows\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

5/22
コードサイニング証明書を取得し問題を解決しました。

Comment: ちなみに、インストールの他の状況は正常か否か？とか。Unity以外のプロジェクトではどうなるか？とかは試してあれば追記してみてください。あと、これらの記事 [Inno Setupによるインストーラの簡単な作り方](https://yun-craft.com/software-crafts/inno-setup), [Inno Setup でインストーラーを作成してみました](https://va2577.github.io/post/112/) を参考に、その通りやってどうなったか、どこか手順を変えたところがあればその内容を追記するとか、やってみてください。

Comment: 私には詳細は判りませんが、これらの記事でUnity+Inno Setupを扱っているようですので参考に。[Create a Unity Installer with Inno Setup](https://blog.kailaharris.com/2019-03-24/install-innosetup/)、[How Can I Package a Unity3D 5 Windows Application into a single exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37190535/9014308)、[Inno Setup script for a Unity Project using Triton Ocean](https://gist.github.com/col000r/9911434)

Comment: インストーラー作成の手順に変更点はなく、テスト的に他exeで作成しても発行元は不明となってしまいました。
Unityで作成したアプリはインストール後正常に動作することは確認できています。

Comment: ちなみに、その「提供元」は、何処でどうやって確認できるものでしょう？

Comment: 発行元はインストーラーを立ち上げた際に確認できます。